# MongoDB aggregation - sum of array of nested objects

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm using **mongo:latest** Docker image (version mongo:7.0.7-jammy as of now)

I'm looking to calculate the sum of an array of nested objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        specificAmount: {
            amount: 200,
        }
    },
    {
        specificAmount: {
            amount: 300,
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

The way I'm tying to do this is:

```
xxx.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        totalSpecificAmount: { $sum: '$specificAmount.amount' || 0 },
      },
    },
 ]).toArray())
```

The counting works correctly, but the calculation of totalSpecificAmount does not - it always returns **zero**

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are those objects an array field of a document or individual documents? You could be scrapping out too much details so it is hard to see where the problem is. My guess would be you might just want to use `$ifNull` to safeguard the null value of `specificAmount.amount` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y02fwIZ6y3k)

Comment: Individual documents

Answer (score 0):

First of all  - thank you @ray for the hint with **$ifNull**

The issue here was that **specificAmount.amount** is not a number as I specified in the question - they are strings and couldn't be summed up.

```
xxx.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        totalSpecificAmount: { 
            $sum: { $ifNull: [{ $toInt: '$specificAmount.amount' }, 0]},
        },
      },
    },
 ]).toArray())
```